# Can I use RVM to maintain a single version of Ruby for all users?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I love RVM. I realize that the main use case for it is letting different users switch between different versions of Ruby. But let's say I'm deploying a Rails app to a server and I just want a single version of Ruby running. In particular, I want 1.9.2, which is a breeze to install with RVM but a pain without it. Is there a way that I can say "I want this to be the canonical Ruby installation for all users" (along with all of its gems) without having to create a bunch of symlinks by hand and change them every time I update to a newer Ruby release?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install RVM as root and do a `sudo rvm use 1.9.2 --default`. Any user sourcing `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` will per default have 1.9.2.

Comment: If you have further questions about RVM, there are people willing to help 24/7 in the #rvm channel on freenode: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Any user sourcing `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`"... I'm thinking in terms of: If I have a web server that runs my Rails app, I want to be sure that it's using Ruby 1.9.2 and the corresponding gems. How do I make the web server user use RVM?

Comment: That really depends on what webserver you use. Sourcing means loading that file into your environment (i.e. place the line `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` in your `/etc/bashrc` or something). Making sure your webserver uses 1.9.2 is essentially the same as making sure it uses the system ruby: It has to be first in the path. That, among other things, is what the rvm sourcing takes care of.

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't quite answer your question, but:

I ran into several problems with installing RVM globally and resorted to using one user account for deployment and for all Ruby / Rails processes -- that users account exists on all dev and production servers, and the .rvm directory is rsync'ed from one dev-server to all other servers.

How many different users on your App servers do really need to access Ruby 1.9.2? 
Can't you just trim that down to just one user?   That worked best for me.

Note:

One thing you probably want to avoid is to install RVM on your app server(s) manually and then install Ruby and Gems on the app server ... you don't want to keep tools like cc lying around on your production servers for security reasons!  rsync'ing the .rvm directory is far safer! and the result is far more consistent!