# How install gem rails for all users in arch-linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, archlinux

When install rails with

```
sudo gem install rails
```

or with root user, this install in `$HOME/.gem` and only works for actual user, how install for all users in the system ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033482/can-i-use-rvm-to-maintain-a-single-version-of-ruby-for-all-users

Comment: But i dont want use RVM, i want a easy installation, but is interesant

Comment: RVM is the definition of an easy installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can comment out gem: --user-install from /etc/gemrc

Answer (score 2):

You can use pacgem which is available in AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacgem