# Is it possible to use a single RVM installation for the entire system?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want to keep a single version of Ruby, Rails, and various gems on my system, for use between multiple users. I attempted to follow the instructions listed at [Can I use RVM to maintain a single version of Ruby for all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033482/can-i-use-rvm-to-maintain-a-single-version-of-ruby-for-all-users) but it did not work, giving me the error `sudo: rvm: command not found` when I ran `sudo rvm use 2.0.0 --default`.

It it possible to keep a system wide installation of all the `ruby` versions, gems, etc. in the `/usr/local/rvm` folder that users in the `rvm` group can access and use/update? Or does each person have to use their own gems in their `~/.rvm` directory?

Comment: Check out [Multi-User Installs - Using the sudo commands](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting/) on the RVM site--in particular, "There is never a reason to use sudo post-install."

Comment: I follow that and install it via `sudo`, and it installs into the `/usr/local/rvm` directory. However after installation, it installs all gems and ruby versions into the `~/.rvm` directory, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not a seasoned RVM user yet, but I've fought similar fights with RVM and Ubuntu. Check if you have a file called `rvm.sh` at `/etc/profile.d`

If you do, start a root shell by typing `sudo bash` and execute `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`, this should make RVM available.

Comment: RVM is a tool that is useful on some systems, and less useful on others (such as Debian). Even without RVM, users can keep their gem sets in sync with, for instance, Bundler.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `sudo` with RVM, that's why there is `rvm` group, any users of `rvm` group should have access to manage rubies and gems.